# Vue modal is not defined - nesting components within components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to nest a component within a component. I am using Laravel and Vue v2.6.11

I want my components to be nested in the following way:

app.js -> Cookie.vue -> Slice.vue

instead I get an error:

```
ReferenceError: slice is not defined                                             app.js:186:5
    ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/Cookie.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:186
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20
    ./resources/js/components/Cookie.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:13961
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20
    vue http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:13922
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20
    js http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:13747
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20
    0 http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:14020
    __webpack_require__ http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:20
    <anonymous> http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/app.js:84
    <anonymous>
```

My current code is:

```
<template>
    <div class="Cookie" id="app-slice">
        <slice></slice>
    </div>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>

Vue.component('slice', require('./Slice.vue'));

new Vue({
    el:'#app-slice',
    components: {
        'slice': slice
        }
});
</script>
```

The slice component worked when it was in app.js however now I am trying to move it to `Cookie.vue`. In app.js I have made it in the following way:

JavaScript:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('cookie', require('./components/Cookie.vue').default);


const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app'
});
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="app">
   <cookie></cookie>
</div>
```

I am lost why it works in app.js but not Cookie.vue

Comment: How does `Slice.vue` look like? If the Vue component is the default export, then you will need to do `Vue.component('slice', require('./Slice.vue').default);`

Comment: If you're adding the `slice` component globally via `Vue.component()`, then you don't need it in the `components` property. Also, in `components: { 'slice': slice }`, `slice` is not defined. You probably want `const slice = require('./Slice.vue').default`

Comment: Thanks so much Phil! It really did work! :D